# How to change the redirect path using ngnix on docker

Tags: nginx

I need one help on `ngnix` which has been installed using docker. I am explaining my code below.

```
location /site {
        # rewrite ^/static(.*) /$1 break;
        # root /static;
        alias /app/static/angular;
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }

    location /node {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    }
```

Using the above code when user is typing `https:localhost:port/site` the index page is loading. But here my requirement is when user will type only `https://localhost:port` on browser then the URl should be changed to `https:localhost:port/site` on browser and same index page will be loaded.any help will be more appreciated.

Comment: Try: `location = / { return 301 /site; }`

Comment: @RichardSmith, I did like `location /  {
        return 301 /site;
        alias /app/static/angular;
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }` but it is removing port after run the url. its coming like `localhost/site`